# Google place autocomplete - how to know selected place is belong to a given state/province or not

Tags: google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google place autocomplete in my website. The user will be redirected to different pages depending on state/province of place they selected.

So my question is: how to get exact state/province of a place the user has selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can get lots of details using

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);
```

Then inspecting the `address_components` should give you `administrative_area_level` you are looking for

See doc at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?#Types for adrress components